# gitignore item for multiple projects

Tags: git, gitignore, git-config

I want to ignore a path in several .git repos, but I don't want to make this global configuration. Say I have this:

```
projects/
    foo/
     .git/
     conf/
    bar/
     .git/
     conf/
    baz/
     .git/
     conf/
```

for all the projects in projects/ I want to ignore any changes to the conf folder. Is there a way to do this with

```
$ git config
```

Because this is a work thing and I share stuff with other devs, I don't want to modify the .gitignore files in each project. I need local settings only.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) manual Git searches for patterns in

- checked in `.gitignore` files,
- `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude` (local, not committed)
- the file pointed to by `git config core.excludesFile` (with `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/ignore` being the default and `~/.config` being the default for the XDG variable).

The simplest method therefore would be a global file in `~/.config/git/ignore` as longs as other git repositories are not affected. Otherwise you can use `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude` but have to configure each repository individually.